# How to find index of a character after space in python

Tags: python, indexing, space

How can I split the below line.

Example:

```
"DHCP discover messages  :   20     DNS Requests  :   20"
```

I want the output to be

```
['DHCP discover messages', '20', 'DNS Requests', '20' ]
```

Comment: How do you know where to perform the split? Sometimes you're splitting on whitespace, sometimes on `:` (with surrounding whitespace), sometimes you don't split when there _is_ whitespace. For example, why split between `20` and `DNS`, but not between `DNS` and `Requests`?

Comment: This also assumes the area between the 20 and the DNS is not a TAB character, I presume...

Comment: This is how it works.

Comment: "This" being...? I see the input, and I see the output, but the examples don't help disambiguate well. If it's always `key_of_mixed_alphabetic_with_possible_spaces : integer_string` then that's good to know, but if the example might have non-integer (or non-numeric) values, that's kind of important. Similarly, if the split point is defined based on spaces vs. tabs, that's also important.

Comment: This is how it works. Find the first ':' and take all the text which is before the colon as first element. Then fetch the numeric available after ':' which is the second element. Again find colon and fetch the third element (DNS requests here). Finally fetch the last numeric (20) as fourth element

Comment: Is the numeric always a non-negative integer value? Or can it be negative? Or a floating point value? Or hell, a complex number?

Comment: "Numeric" is a lot broader than "non-negative integer". `1.3` is numeric. `-232497` is numeric. `1.3e9` is numeric. `12+2j` is numeric. While not a Python legal literal (at least, not making a `fractions.Fraction`), `3/7` is numeric. Do you mean "non-negative integer" or something else?

Comment: guess quite all the answers works :)

Comment: @ShadowRanger It's always a positive integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the whole line consist of several text : number pairs, first split should be done on each colon.

Then all parts except the first and the last  should be split on the first whitespace.

Example input string:

```
"t 1 : n1   t t 2 : n2   t t t 3 : n3"
```

After the first `split(':')`:

```
["t 1 ", " n1   t t 2 ", " n2   t t t 3 ", " n3"]
```

After `split(None, 1)` on all elements except the first and the last one:

```
["t 1 ", ["n1",  "t t 2 "], ["n2", "t t t 3 "], " n3"]
```

Finally flatten the list and trim any extra whitespace:

```
["t 1", "n1",  "t t 2", "n2", "t t t 3", "n3"]
```

Edit: code example:

```
def mysplit(line):
    split1 = line.split(':')
    last = len(split1) - 1 
    for i, t1 in enumerate(split1):
        if i == 0 or i == last:
            yield t1.strip()
        else:
            for t2 in t1.split(None, 1): 
                yield t2.strip()

testline = "t 1 : n1   t t 2 : n2   t t t 3 : n3" 
testsplit = list(mysplit(testline))
print(testsplit)
# prints ['t 1', 'n1', 't t 2', 'n2', 't t t 3', 'n3']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi, How do I get to the last step? '["n1",  "t t 2 "]' is showing as a single element. But, I want it to be separated like you have in the final step.Is there any other method available apart from accessing it as **newlist[0][0]** and '**newlist[0][1]**

Comment: @RakeshNittur: You could search for "Python list flattening", it has been answered many times before. However you can take care of this issue when creating the list. See the sample code I have added to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
import re

str = 'DHCP discover messages  :   20     DNS Requests  :   20'

[l.strip() for l in re.sub(r'(\d+) +(\w)', r'\1:\2', str).split(':')]

#['DHCP discover messages', '20', 'DNS Requests', '20']
```

Comment: `l<>''` is archaic (deprecated for ages in Py2, and non-existent in Py3), and pointless when `l` is a `str` and you can just test `if l` without comparing to anything (the empty `str` being falsy, and non-empty being truthy). Also, really bad form to stomp on `str`; `astr`, `mystr`, `s`; any of those are better than `str` (which would shadow access to the `str` constructor).

Comment: I suppressed this if condition in the list comprehension with a slightly better regex to have the desired result. I remind for `if l` however!

Answer (score 1):

A short example using regex.

```
print([
    (l.strip(), v.strip())
    for l, v in re.findall(
        "(?P<label>[^:]+):(?P<value>[ 0-9]+)",
        example
    )
])
[('DHCP discover messages', '20'), ('DNS Requests', '20')]
```

Comment: The OP wants to find the index of the matches too (I think)

Comment: @CoryKramer "I need to fetch the numbers after ":"." - he needs the values, not the index. He thinks substrings are the only way to do it.

Comment: @ TkTech Can I split the elements onto a single list?

Comment: You could flatten it back with `itertools.chain.from_iterable` (possibly wrapped in a `list` call), but if the data is naturally paired, you probably don't _want_ to.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
x="DHCP discover messages  :   20     DNS Requests  :   20"
print [i for i in re.split(r"\s*:\s*\b(\d+\b)\s*",x) if i]
```

Output:`['DHCP discover messages', '20', 'DNS Requests', '20']`